# How to close a modal with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I send a ajax request to a web server, the server returns me a value, if the value is true, I have to close the modal, when I close the modal I can't surf into the page.

**AJAX Code**

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "impostazioni/funzioni.php",
data: { "action": "aggiorna", "tipo": "EMail", "valore": nuova},
success:function(result){
    $("#nuova_email").val("");
    $("#conferma_email").val("");
    $("#modifica_mail").hide();
    alert("EMail aggiornata");
    $("#email").val(nuova);
    impostazioni();
}
});
```

**HTML Modal**

```
<div id="modifica_mail" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modifica e-mail</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table" style="border:none; line:none;overflow-x:auto; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;width: 100%;border: 1px solid #ddd;">
                <tr>
                    <td>Nuova e-mail</td>
                    <td><input type="email" placeholder="Nuova e-mail" id="nuova_email" name="nuova_e-mail"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Conferma e-mail</td>
                    <td><input type="email" placeholder="Conferma e-mail" id="conferma_email" name="conferma_e-mail"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="annulla_email()" data-dismiss="modal">Annulla</button>
            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="aggiorna_email()">Aggiorna</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Paste your html code here. Don't use image for showing code.

Comment: use `$("#modifica_mail").modal("hide");` instead of `$("#modifica_mail").hide();`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-methods

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$("#modifica_mail").hide();
```

into correct Bootstrap modal function.

```
$("#modifica_mail").modal('hide');
```

More details here.
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#modalhide

Comment: I tried your html code. Its working on my end.
Maybe there's an error on your ajax request?
It should be successful.